# A recurrence for a combinatorial problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

$N$ balls are tossed into $n$ boxes independently. Each ball has a $1/n$ chance of falling into any box.$$P_{N,n}(k):= Pr\{exactly\:k\:empty\:boxes\:after\:N\:balls\:thrown\:into\:n\:boxes\}$$
Show that:$$P_{N,n}(k) = (1-\frac{1}{n})^NP_{N,n-1}(k-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\binom{N}{i}(\frac{1}{n^i})(1-\frac{1}{n})^{N-i}P_{N-i,n-1}(k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The first term describes the situation in which box $n$ is empty. Term $i$ in the second sum (that should really go from $1$ to $N$) describes the situation in which box $n$ has $i$ balls.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the index; corrected. Yes, the first term is simpler, by keeping the "additional" box empty we increase the number of empty boxes by 1 (k-1 ->k). I understand what you're saying about the second term: what about the case where one of the original k empty boxes gets filled but the "additional" box remains empty? And there are N-i additional balls, right?

Comment: This case doesn't happen.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning about the second term in more detail? Thanks

Comment: No, my hint should be enough. Spend a few hours on this, and eventually you'll get it.

Comment: You are right (more than once), it was easy. Basically all the ways the additional box not being empty (receiving i balls) times the rest of the system (of size n-1) receiving those balls (N-i), with k empty. Thanks. I have another [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284854/a-convolution-involving-binomials) that makes me chase my own tail, could you please take a look at it offer a hint? Thanks again.